# Provide documentation for C++ class exposed via Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

Suppose I have a small C++ class where I have inlined all the functions (and attempted to document via Roxygen per [[Section 3.4]](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-attributes.pdf)):

```
class HelloWorld {
private:
    int count;
public:
//' the constructor for the class
HelloWorld() : count(0) {}

//' my magical function
//' @param arg the integer to add
//' @return the magical result
int example(int arg) { return 2*count+arg; }
};
```

I can expose this class to Rcpp:

```
RCPP_MODULE(helloworld){
    Rcpp::class_<HelloWorld>("HelloWorld")
        .constructor()
        .method("example", &HelloWorld::example, "A magical function.");
};
```

However, the generated R/RcppExports.R from Rcpp.package.skeleton() looks like

```
#' the constructor for the class
NULL

#' Inserts an entry into the dictionary
#' @param arg the integer to add
#' @return the magical result
NULL
```

I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: We can't tell as your example is incomplete / not reproducible.  Maybe you forgot a Modules declaration of the class?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. What do you mean by missing modules declaration of the class? Isn't that what the RCPP_MODULE macro is?

And, is my example incomplete? If I stuff the class code I provided with the RCPP_MODULE bit in a .cpp file (and put a #include <Rcpp.h> at the top), then it runs just fine. When I run from R:
    require(Rcpp);
    Rcpp.package.skeleton("helloworld", cpp_files="helloworld.cpp");
I get the R/RcppExports.R file with the NULL entries.

Comment: Rcpp.package.skeleton() has a modules argument ...   And if it works written by hand, why not keep it that way?

Comment: Hello again. I have now tried specifying the modules argument with no success (same results as before). I'm more than happy to manually create my Rd file, but I was hoping to do things "properly" since this is my first attempt at an R package.

Comment: If you expectation is that some part of the Rcpp package is going to write Roxygen for you then you will .... have to adjust your expectations. Not sure what gave you that idea.

Comment: I think you're misunderstood my question -- section 3.4 of the Rcpp-attribute vignette says exactly:
"If you include roxygen comments in your C++ source file with a //' prefix then compileAttributes will transpose them into R roxygen comments within R/RcppExports.R"

While compileAttributes() is finding my Roxygen comments, it is not picking up the method declarations immediately following.

Comment: Sure, and that works as advertised and is widely used _for Function_. But AFAIK It just does not say or imply that it _also documents Modules_ which is how you read it.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thanks for your (considerable) patience in explaining it to me. :-)

Comment: No worries. Would be nice to have Modules magically roxygenized but sadly there is no magic pony for that yet...